# Access dynamically added properties in loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am adding properties to an object using for loop. While in the loop I'm unable to access properties previously added.

```
let props= ["a","b","a"]; const obj ={}
for(let x of props) obj[x] = obj[x] ? obj[x]++ : 0;
obj; // expecting { a:1, b:0 }
```

Why is this happening? Does the object get prepared after the loop is completed?
How can I overcome this if it's a language limitation?

Comment: `obj[x] = (obj[x] ?? 0) + 1;` would be way better

Comment: Very useful, I had never heard of this operator. I learned something today :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm setting the value to be zero which causes the if statement to fail :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your ternary operator :

```
obj[x] = obj[x] ? obj[x]++ : 0;
```

On the first loop, if the property doesn't exist, you initialize it to `0`, that's fine.

Then the problem arises : your ternary operator is not testing `does the key exist?` but instead is testing for any falsy value... and 0 is a falsy value, so it gets initialized to 0 again, instead of incrementing!

Second problem spotted by Jonas : `obj[x] = obj[x]++` doesn't make sense, it should be `obj[x] = obj[x] + 1`.

In order for it to work, use :

```
for(let x of props) obj[x] = (typeof obj[x]==="number") ? obj[x] + 1 : 0;
```

Comment: So `obj[x] = obj[x]++` makes sense to you?

Comment: Ah, that's another problem indeed, I didn't spot that. Let me correct my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

obj.hasOwnProperty(x) ? obj[x]++ : obj[x] = 0

Answer (score 0):

My approach for this to use **reduce** util function. basically reduce returns the accumulator that we have passed with updates that we want to carry out in that accumulator.

Let me make this easy.

In reduce method I am passing the empty object as an accumulator. On every interations we are checking already property is present if present increase value by 1 or just assign 0 to that property.

```js
let keys = ["a", "b", "a"]
let obj = keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = acc.hasOwnProperty(key) ? ++acc[key] : 0; 
  return acc;
}, {})
console.log(obj);
```